# Outputting a Joined Table

Tags: php, mysql, database, left-join

I am currently trying to output a joined table.

The two joined tables consist of the `Customer` table:

[image]

as well as the `Address` table:

[image]

However I am getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: Street

This error is happening for every joined index from the `Address` table (so it's also happening for `Postcode` `City` and `Country` as well).

My question is how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why your getting undefined is that your not using your joined row to execute.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM Customer LEFT JOIN Address USING (AddressID)');
$stmt->execute();
```

This code above is what gets your joined code your then instantly overwriting $stmt with a new one that does not have the joined data inside it.

Delete these 2 lines of code.

```
$stmt = $pdo -> prepare('SELECT * FROM Customer');
$stmt -> execute();
```

And it will work.

As a side note, you are making your code far harder to read in your CustomerRowOutput method.

when using the variable replace system inside double quotes you can use arrays. just wrap them in curly braces `{}`

So your current syntax `<tr><td>$cn</td>...</tr>` should be `<tr><td>{$customerRow['CustomerName']}</td>...</tr>` curly bracers wrapping an array like that will allow it to be output. this also saves on memory as your not creating pointers purly to make echoing easier.

and PHP also supports newlines in string type variables. so that whole function can become

```
function CustomerRowOutput($customerRow){
    return "<tr>
        <td>{$customerRow['CustomerName']}</td>
        <td>{$customerRow['PhoneNo']}</td>
        <td>{$customerRow['Email']}</td>
        <td>{$customerRow['Street']}</td>
        <td>{$customerRow['Postcode']}</td>
        <td>{$customerRow['City']}</td>
        <td>{$customerRow['Country']}</td>
    </tr>";
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: I have also added a little advance about your output to make it more readable.

Comment: excellent points. if for some reason OP wants to avoid newline characters, then add just a little more syntax, leaving the code formatted as shown in this answer, one per line, but concatenate (dot operator) a series of strings without the newline e.g.  `. "<td>{$custRow['City']}</td>"`.  We might also note that the value being returned from the database isn't guaranteed not to contain html., consider the impact of e.g. a crafty `street` value `foo</td></tr>Hey!<tr><td>` or something more nefarious. best practice would be to wrap potentially unsafe values in `htmlentities` function.

Comment: i think @spencer7593 means `. "<td>" . htmlentities($customerRow['Street']) . "</td>"` and i was assuming that the values we're escaped / entitie encoded before entry :D

Comment: @MartinBarker: another absolutely good point. i was thinking the entries weren't html encoded in the database, because in our shop they are not html encoded (by design) and that's because database entries are also used by other processes, and output in ways other than emitting them on an HTML page. (we leave html encoding to the very last, right at the presentation layer, right where an entry is being included into an HTML page.) This pattern also aids code verification, we don't have to track back through the whole system to verify that html encoding has been done (and not later undone)